# Implementing DNS Redundancy - Web Hosting

Tags: domain-name-system, redundancy, dns-hosting

After our domain registrar/name server host went down we have found that DNS is a major single point of failure as its also taken down all of our email (Office365), web, hosted services etc..

I want to get some redundancy around it, is it a simple matter of moving my DNS records to Route53 or DNS made easy (etc.. etc..) or do I need one of their addons to get redundancy?

Our dns is though a cheaperdomains.com.au - so even moving to a specific DNS hosting may be sufficient?

Answer (score 1):

Most registrars have some method of changing your NS records to another DNS host. You can use that to point your domain at a different set of DNS servers.

Some services can "transfer" your zone seamlessly as well (using AXFR records and slave zones). I use this personally on a personal domain name as a 3rd and 4th nameserver so I always have 4 servers in sync with each other for my domain name.

Answer (score 1):

Tyron,

I have migrated a couple of my zone records for different web sites that I have to Route53. I can tell you that the service is amazing and it's very simple to setup, you create the zone file (Route53) and upon the creation of such zone, you will receive information regarding the name servers that Route 53 has assigned to you (typically 4 name servers for high availability).

Now, you need to update your zone file (registrar) and update the name servers to point to the IP addresses that Route 53 gave you.

Hopefully it helps you and good luck!

Cheers!